# Replace '-' in slug array with '/'

Tags: slug, bolt-cms, bolt

So I've created my first website based on Bolt CMS and I can't fininsh one, last task.

The task is to make simple routes:

list of records from selected category - `/realizations/cool-category`

list of all records - `/realizations/`

single record - `/realizations/cool-category/product1`

I've managed to make it work but I can't manage to use record taxonomy (category) in routing file to set link like above.

I mean something like that : `path: /{contenttypeslug}/{category_gotes_here}/{slug}/`

Because of that, one (I guess horrible) idea appeared in my head - make slug use record title field and its category field.

Unfortunately slug's `uses: [title, category]` returns `/title-category/` while I need `/title/category/` format.

It there any way to make this one work? Or is there another, more valid way to add record category before its title in routing?

Answer (score 0):

Bolt usually is not equipped to handle paths with more than one "/".

But you can expand the options with custom routes https://docs.bolt.cm/3.5/configuration/routing

For examples you can look at https://market.bolt.cm/view/twokings/hierarchical-routes - Or you can just use this extension to add more hierarchy.